# Detox - test | Android | ChildProcessError: Command failed

Tags: macos, android-studio, react-native, adb, detox

`detox test -c ios.debug` is running tests fine.

`detox build -c android.debug` builds fine too each time.

But `detox test -c android.debug` is giving this issue.

It seems to be related to the Android SDK path.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, it turned out to be Detox looking in the system path that had incomplete Android Studio files/folders, rather than the local user path that had them all.

You will notice you have a symbolic link called `android-sdk` in:

> Macintosh HD⁩ ▸ ⁨usr⁩ ▸ ⁨local⁩ ▸ ⁨share⁩

That points to something like:

> ‎⁨Macintosh HD⁩ ▸ ⁨usr⁩ ▸ ⁨local⁩ ▸ ⁨Caskroom⁩ ▸ ⁨android-sdk⁩ ▸ 4333796

Simply backup this original symbolic link, then create a new one with the same name in the same location, that instead points to:

> ‎⁨Macintosh HD⁩ ▸ ⁨Users⁩ ▸ ⁨{user}⁩ ▸ ⁨Library⁩ ▸ ⁨Android⁩ ▸ sdk

And voila, it should now be able to find `platform-tools` and run your tests.